# In Yahoo! Finance, what determines the number of decimals for a stock/index quote?

Tags: finance, visualization, yahoo, price, quote

In [Yahoo! Finance](http://finance.yahoo.com/), we see the following quotes among others:

```
Nasdaq  3,136.19     -13.27 -0.42%
Oil        89.879997  -1.83 -2.00%
EUR/USD     1.3031     0.00 +0.11%
```

What determines the number of decimals displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of *minimum price variation* (also known as the minimum price *increment* or the minimum price *fluctuation*).

All *public* quotes for US equities are displayed to the nearest penny. (Hidden quotes may be entered at sub-penny increments.) US stock indices follow this convention and thus quote to the nearest penny.

The oil listing is odd indeed. If I click through to the full oil page, I only see that the price is listed to the nearest penny. Indeed, I see that this price represents the NYMEX crude (CL) contract. From the CME Group's [contract specification](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/crude-oil/light-sweet-crude_contract_specifications.html), the minimum fluctuation is one penny per barrel. So it's bizarre that Yahoo's front page is showing something else.

As for the Euro, that's a spot price. I can't see exactly where Yahoo is getting their data, but they do describe it as "bank rates". ([Google gets theirs from Citi](http://www.google.com/intl/en/help/currency_disclaimer.html).) I suspect the convention is 0.0001 dollars increment per euro since that's what [CME Group uses in the futures market](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/fx/g10/e-mini-euro-fx_contract_specifications.html).